# Disable automatic session save in Codeigniter (duplicating a Codeigniter project to shared hosting)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a running system on VPS server, but I need to make a copy of it on another shared hosting server.
I have copied all files to new shared hosting server.
But after running my system, I am getting exception:

> Session: Configured save path '' is not a directory, doesn't exist or cannot be created.

How can I fix this?

As I am using Codeigniter 3 and PHP 5.6 version.

Comment: give a path for files to save. that should solve the error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you to provide an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve – this way it'll be easier for us to help and you may find the problem and the solution yourself this way (this often works for me this way). Best regards

Answer (score 0):

In config/config.php

Replace: $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;

**With: $config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();**

Comment: I do not want to save session neither in files nor in database, so what I can do for this?

Comment: Comment out all session functions in config.php
and remove session library from autoload

Comment: Done with this but then my index page is not working

Comment: blank page :(, I have Codeigniter version 3.1.4